# C# code to start selenium-server on remote machine

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, selenium, nunit

As part of my test automation, I have to start Selenium Server on my server.

As of now I am manually executing a batch file to start selenium server on m,y machine.

Batch file contains the following command.

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.16.1.jar -role hub http://server.com:5555/grid/register
```

But as I required it for my test automation, I want to automate running the selenium server on a remote server from my C# code. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://unintelligible.org/blog/2009/07/28/installing-selenium-rc-as-a-windows-service/